# Display users online use websocket, aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I am doing the function of displaying users who are online using websocket. I follow here: https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app I've done successfully. It will create 3 lambda function: onConnect, sendMess, onDisconnect. Receiving and sending messages to all clients is ok. If a user accesses the website, will send that user data(name, avatar..) to the server.

But I currently don't know how to handle connect and disconnect on the server with that data. How to send message from server to all client when a client disconnect. Hope you can teach me. Thank you very much.

[image: user online]

Comment: This is really too broad to ask here. But I'll point you to a very good youtube video which taught me how to do websockets with AWS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weYQvbjhU2A

Comment: @404 Everything in that video I've done successfully. I have received and sent messages to all clients. If a user accesses the website, will send that user data(name, avatar..) to the server.  But I currently don't know how to handle connect and disconnect on the server to display users online.